# Can ship upgrades be linked?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I know about the linking bonuses in the exosuit/multi-tool, and I'm wondering if the same mechanic applies to your ship. I put two similar components next to each other, but I don't see any UI indication that linking is in effect.

**Update**: It turns out that the items need to be in good repair for the mechanic to take effect.

Comment: I am fairly confident that the linking effect you see in the exosuit also applies to the multitool. As such, it's logical to conclude that the ship's upgrades can be similarly linked, since they all have similar inventory systems.

Comment: I'm also operating on that assumption, but again, I don't see any feedback from the UI indicating that the mechanic is in effect; and I don't know how to compare my stats to the ship's baseline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes they do work the same way as the multi-tool upgrades.

If you have connected Pulse Jet upgrades they are highlighted as a dark blue which is sort of hard to see. That might be what you are experiencing.

[Here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgICy.jpg) for reference

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Actually I was seeing a Beam Coolant upgrade adjacent to a Beam Impact which I misread as a Coolant. They look so similar, and the scrolling text on the icon didn't help. Good to know I can optimize.

Comment: They should still interact with each other, for example I just uploaded a picture of my ship that has cannon damage with accelerated fire next to each other, both highlighted red. Are you sure they were both beam upgrades and not one for cannon one for phase beam?

Comment: Definitely both beam: Phase Coolant Sigma adjacent to Beam Impact Sigma. The issue was that one needed repair; I found the ship abandoned and hadn't yet repaired everything. Embarassing :) I'll leave the question in case anyone is as ditzy as me.